# What is the most minimal code to work with ConTeXt?

Tags: context

What is the most minimal code to work with ConTeXt?

Comment: "work with"?  What kind of work do you have in mind?

Comment: @Charles: To make it compilable.

Comment: To test that your set up is working?

Comment: @Charles: Yes. I want to make a test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the most minimal. It just instructs TeX to stop.

```
\end
```

While I'm at it. It's also the most minimal code for plain TeX. For LaTeX, the best I could do is this.

```
\csname@@end\endcsname
```

I guess

```
\catcode`@11 \@@end
```

is shorter, but it's less minimal since TeX has to execute two commands instead of just one.

Comment: @TH `\stop` for LaTeX should be the shorter?

Comment: @Yiannis: Ah yes. Probably the shortest, but not the most minimal. It invokes the output routine.

Comment: What about `\enddocument` in LaTeX? Probably also not minimal, since that requires an `aux` file present.

Comment: @Konrad: That doesn't work. As you mentioned, it looks for `\jobname.aux`.

Answer (score 5):

```
\starttext
Hello world.
\stoptext
```

or even simpler

```
Hello world.
\bye
```

Comment: Well, actually I'm not a ConTeXt user. http://wiki.contextgarden.net/First_Document

Comment: how about just `\bye`?

Comment: @Yiannis: In fact, there's no difference, right? I think the key is "work" but not "most minimal". The first example works as most ConTeXt ducuments, and the second one works as Plain TeX.

Answer (score 0):

According to ConTeXt Garden,

```
.
```

[is the minimal working example](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/MWE) *which produces a page* and it is for both LuaTeX/MkIV and LuaMetaTeX/LMTX. It produces a blank PDF with a page number. Yeah, new answer to old question, but it's still shorter than `\end` :)

As Henri points out, ConTeXt will run with an empty input file, but it won't produce any PDF.

Comment: In fact, ConTeXt will even compile an empty file (but doesn't produce a PDF), whereas LaTeX will stop and ask for input.

Comment: @HenriMenke I know the former because I accidentally did it before (Lua stuff without TeX output). I didn't know about the latter, tho. Nice remark.